# Swagger springfox hide model property on POST

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Would like to know how to hide a model property in Swagger on POST. I have tried both Swagger-springmvc (0.9.3) and Springfox (supports swagger spec 2.0) to no avail.

Problem being I would like to see this in the GET requests through Swagger. But not POST requests, since id is auto-assigned, I would like to hide it just for the POST request.

```
public class RestModel {
   private int id;
   @JsonProperty
   private String name;

   @JsonProperty
   public int getId() {
       return 0;
   }

   @JsonIgnore
   public void setId(int customerId) {
       this.customerId = customerId;
   }

   public int getName() {
       return "abc";
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

So on GET, I should see:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name" : "abc"
}
```

And on POST, I should see just:

```
{
   "name"
}
```

Tried adding: @ApiModelProperty(readonly=true). But that didn't help.

Comment: Hi RG1, I tried @ApiModelProperty(readonly=true) when I'm using springfox-3.0.0, it works.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this with simply extending the Object that I want to hide a property of when using as request parameter.

Example:

I have the object Person.java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Years;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

/**
 * Simple Person pojo
 */
@Entity
public class Person {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long dbId;
    private String name;

    private Long id;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date birthDate;
    private String gender;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(long dbId) {
        this.dbId = dbId;
    }

    public Person(Long id, String name, Date birthDate, String gender) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Long getDbId() {
        return dbId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return Years.yearsBetween(new DateTime(birthDate), new DateTime()).getYears();
    }

    public void setDbId(Long dbId) {
        this.dbId = dbId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I have simply created another class: PersonRequest.java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
public class PersonRequest extends Person {

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public void setDbId(Long dbId) {
        super.setDbId(dbId);
    }
}
```

RequestMapping looks simply like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/KVFirstCare/application", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ApplicationResult application(@RequestBody List<PersonRequest> persons,
                                     HttpServletResponse response) {
}
```

Works like charm :)

Comment: I found this (extending models and adding JsonIgnore wherever necessary) to be the easiest way to solve this problem. I agree with @thejeff, it would be nice to solve this by pure swagger annotations and not affecting business functions.

Comment: Its a solution but it has code smell, I am in the same boat and would not reccomend using this in production

Comment: @SteelToe, could you please elaborate why you think this is a code smell? And what kind of negative effect this can have in production?

Comment: Extending an object just to hide a property on a json representation is by definition code smell, Your answer is fine, I just wish there would be a cleaner way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately having different request and response models is not supported currently in springfox. The current thought is that we might support this feature using @JsonView in the future.

Comment: @Dilip Krishnan we would also love to hear if this will be implemented

Comment: @MariánZekeŠedaj this has already [been implemented](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/pull/2056) it’s not merged in yet but it will be soon.

Comment: I can see fields are ignored in Swagger with @JsonIgnore, however this prevents a field from being serialized to the client on all requests (POST and GET alike), and affects business logic. Would be nice to have the ability to define the docs only without affecting business function through the API - I.E. (JsonIgnore or JsonView)