# Swagger - Springfox - How to exclude properties from model classes only for some operations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-2.0

I would like to document the "get" and "create" operations for a `Resource (Integer id, String name)` object. When I configure Swagger with Springfox in a Spring MVC application the documentation shows:

```
GET /resources -> Model: { "id" : 0 , "name" : "string"}
POST /resources -> Request body:  { "id" : 0 , "name" : "string"}
                -> Response 201:  { "id" : 0 , "name" : "string"}
```

The point is that the "id" parameter shouldn't be in the POST body, since it'll be created in the operation. My question is, is there a way to indicate that some property should be excluded from the documentation only in some cases?

Comment: Can you use the hidden field of [@ApiModelProperty](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html#hidden%28%29)?

Comment: The problem is that if I hide the id field with @ApiModelProperty so that it doesn't appear in the POST model, it won't be shown in the GET response Model either.

Comment: There's a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995077/swagger-springfox-hide-model-property-on-post)